# Is there any feature to Vote To Accept

Tags: feature-request

**Incident**

Some new users join to stack family. And they ask some thing hard or best question. So our Stack buddy's answer that question. And the answer was an very advanced one and Superb one.(as my knowledge). But what OP do is place an comment **Its worked....**  rather than accepting it. and thy never come back.

**Suggestion**

If user is **below some rep**(assume 50-) and the **not logged in to site more than some time**(assume 1 month), there is **feature** automatically get **added to answer Vote to accept**.

So ***Moderators*** can accept as Stack rule by ***one click***. and ***other have to vote that***. (ex: Close to vote). after some vote (assume 8) it will be flagged with  accept with green color accepted mark.

**For readers**

If you have any better idea feel free to add this with alone with your name

> ***post this for not get vote. just an request.***
>
> **If any down-voters please mentioned it in by commenting. I respect your ideas**

Comment: @Elltz ya. an answer should depend to OPs Question so. if he tld its worked. then it should be accept. thats my point

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the help center on [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally**, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

Bold added for emphasis.

The accept mark means that the answer worked for a single person. *Upvotes* (and downvotes) indicate that an answer is helpful to *multiple* people. This is true even when an answer is accepted. There are countless questions that have accepted answers scoring lower than competing answers.